# Mass checking and renaming for illegal characters in both files and folders

Tags: linux, terminal, mv

I wrote a python script in which it reads a text file that contains thousands of folder directory.
While executing my script, I added in `du -sch` to try and get an approximate total size of all these directories but it results in error as I found out them, in these folder path and the contents within, it contains illegal characters such as whitespace, colon, apostrophe etc.

Example: /serverA/reference images/set1A's/JPG/

Assuming that /serverA/ has 5000 folders, say the text file contains 3000 of the paths, only a few hundreds of them require re-naming. What is the best way that I can check and replace such illegal characters to both folders and the folder contents?

I suppose I may need to run the command at /serverA/ level?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that your text file was created as a one-off (as opposed to being regularly created by a script/process), you should simply load it into a text editor that has a good search/replace function - such as Notepad++.

You can then run a series of search/replace commands to remove invalid characters.

Note that some whitespace is perfectly legal in file/folder names of course, also watch out if using non-english versions of an OS as these might use Unicode characters.

Comment: The text file that I have does not consists of the entire folder directory within /serverA/

Comment: Meaning? Perhaps you should re-phrase your question to say what it is that you are actually trying to achieve.

Comment: Okay I have added an example, and reedited my post, hopefully that makes more sense?